# Selecting count of records with different gender but same first name and last name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like below

| unique_id | first_name | last_name | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | smith | M |
| 2 | kevin | jones | M |
| 3 | kevin | jones | F |

In this example, records with unique_ids #2 and #3 are the same person with a different gender.
I want to identify the count of such records. In this case, the output is 1, as the table has duplicates for one person.
TIA for any pointers.

Comment: what is the expected result if you have two "kevin jones, m" and two "kevin jones, f"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by first and last name and then use the HAVING clause to keep only those combinations with more than one result.  I like using a common table expression as shown below because you can easily output the underlying rows for troubleshooting purposes.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
    unique_id int,
    first_name varchar(20),
    last_name varchar(20),
    gender char(1)
)

INSERT @tbl(unique_id, first_name, last_name, gender) 
VALUES 
    (1, 'john', 'smith', 'M'),
    (2, 'kevin', 'jones', 'M'),
    (3, 'kevin', 'jones', 'F')

;WITH cteDupes AS (
    SELECT 
        first_name, last_name
    FROM 
        @tbl
    GROUP BY 
        first_name, last_name 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

-- To see the actual names with dupes
-- SELECT * FROM cteDupes

-- To see the count only
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cteDupes
```

Comment: I would prefer `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT gender) > 1` to prevent to count really duplicated rows where first_name, last_name and gender are all identic.

Comment: Thanks,  this is perfect. CTE for the win :)